# split by "|" operator in Java

Tags: java, split

I want to split a string by `|` in java but as split function in java accepts regular expressions and `|` means or operator, I am not sure what I should provide the split function with?

Comment: So many related answers...The `|` character is called the `pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

Provide escape sequence before `|`, something like this : `\\|`

```
String str = "abc|pqr";
String[] split=str.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the String with [`Pattern.quote(String s);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) before passing it to the split() method